# URL redirect to use subdirectory as GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, subdirectory

I imagine this has to be a common scenario but I'm struggling to describe it sufficiently well or to find a working answer!

Essentially I want to make hundreds of URLS that include unique reference codes but that are easy to type in the form `example.com/aabbcc`, which will be intercepted and all delivered to a PHP script for validating that code, located somewhere like `example.com/script.php`.
I need the subdirectory part of the URL (aabbcc, in this example) to become a GET parameter for that script, so a URL like the one above would be sent to `example.com/script.php?id=aabbcc`, while hiding this more complicated URL from the user.

I can see from other .htaccess examples that this must be possible, but I can't find one doing this.

Is there a .htaccess solution for it? Is there something else even more basic? Your help is appreciated in steering me.

Comment: What is the precise format of the "unique reference code"? In your example the code consists of 6 lowercase letters - is that the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "unique reference codes" consist of 6 lowercase letters, as in your example then you can do something like the following in your root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine

# Internally rewrite "/abcdef" to "script.php?id=abcdef"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{6}$ script.php?id=$0 [L]
```

If you don't need direct access to any subdirectories off the root that also happen to match a "unique reference code" then you can remove the preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive). With the *condition* in place then you naturally can't access any "unique access codes" that happen to also match the name of a subdirectory.

`$0` is a backreference to the entire URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) matches against.

---

#### Reference

- [Apache mod-rewrite Documentation - Contents](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/)
- **[Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)**
- [Apache mod_rewrite Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

  - [`RewriteRule` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
  - [`RewriteCond` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: This is very helpful; thank you. The codes will probably be 6-character letter and number codes, which I can see how to amend for in the example you gave. There won't be subdirectories that match those names.